# Malware on my Linux? Cant see on top/htop but CPU/Mem Usage is high

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, malware

Over about the last week or two, I have been seeing something odd with my Linux mint PC.

Over a day or 2, at some point, my CPU usage hits and saturates at or near 100 at some point (according to my conky, htop shows 1 of my CPUs saturated at 100% in red). Now I see that my memory usage is starting to reach extremely high levels (3gb) while the highest mem usage process is firefox, by far(600mb).

Is it possible I have some sort of virus/malware/rootkit? I understand that this kind of behavior is the forte of rootkits. If possible, is there a way for me to fix this? Or just reinstall?

TL;DR - Often my CPU Usage and/or my Mem Usage is high, but top/htop do not show any processes that might be responsible for this.

Comment: I'd start by determining the process responsible for the usage before jumping to conclusions, but if you do find you are infected, a scorched-earth rebuild is a good idea. if you can't even monitor your processes though, perhaps a reboot with the magic reisub is in order.

Comment: High RAM usage is normal. Operating systems try as hard as they can to use as much RAM as possible. Any RAM not used is forever wasted. It's not like an 8GB machine can use 4GB today so it can use 12GB tomorrow. RAM that's not being used it no better than RAM that's not in the machine. As for the CPU usage, that might be a real problem, but most likely you're just not diagnosing it correctly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand what you are saying, but I believe htop shows, in its numbers, only the amount actually used(reserved is it?), and not the cached part as well

Comment: @FrankThomas Sound advice, but as I say, I cant see a process that can be responsible, hence my predicament. I read that rootkits are processes that hide other malicious processes from tools like top and ps, thus my conclusion. Today, this issue also drastically slowed(mouse lag, typing lag, switching workspace lag, etc) my PC, until it eventually froze,

Comment: @KarthikT That doesn't change anything. The best way to use the RAM may change based on the workload. For example, it might be used to make existing memory mapping resident, which is not considered cache. Or it might be used by a memory balloon driver, which is again not considered cache.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So would resident not be considered either of "buffers" or "cache"? The reason I am concerned is that I have never seen it so bad, times when my ram reaches so high includes when firefox is well over 1gb(it was half that now), vagrant was running(it wasnt now) and sublime was open(wasnt now). And this situation escalated, afaik, quite fast, over the course of minutes perhaps.

Comment: @KarthikT How is that bad? Is memory being wasted good? Memory is "use it or lose it". Why would you prefer the latter to the former?! If you think it's bad to use so much memory, take some out of your system and then it will use less. Of course it will perform worse, which is why you want your system to use as much memory as it can.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If this issue was not accompanied by 1/2 CPU hung at 100% (kernel according to htop) and in drastic swapping style slowdown followed by all out freeze, then I would concede you were right.. However I do not believe these events are disconnected

Comment: @KarthikT You need to figure out what the CPU is doing and also determine whether the machine is actually paging.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and my question is How, when htop doesnt show any processes at such high CPU, what can I do. ALso i do not believe my machine was swapping, it just felt like that. The swap used was 0/minimal. Didnt have the sense to run iotop during that time, though not sure if that woulda shown anything either

Comment: @KarthikT Heat can do this. Maybe your CPU fan is failing? Does it sound normal? Check your heat sink and all fans. Did you make any configuration changes?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Doesnt sound likely, no major config changes, machine is open and has a good/working fan/heatsink combo. Onset is too sudden for heat based imo